# How to use github and ec2 together to deploy a python application

Tags: python, github, amazon-ec2

I am currently using github to develop a python application and am looking to deploy it on EC2.

Is there a good way to automatically handle the messiness this entails (setting up SSH key pairs on the EC2 instance for github, pulling from the github repository every time a commit is pushed to the master branch, etc.) without a bunch of custom scripts?  Alternatively, is there an open-source project that has focused on this?

Comment: You may want to look at github's post-receive hooks and have it push instead of your server pulling.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [simple python script](https://gist.github.com/228427) to do this once. I also [posted about it](http://jakewharton.com/post/2813460095/automatic-github-hook-puller-for-easy-deployment) on my blog.

You set up mappings of your repositories and brances to point to local folders which already contain a checkout of that repo and branch. Then, you enable GitHub's post-receive hooks to hit the script which will then automatically trigger a `git pull` in the appropriate folder.